# How to apply different styles on a paragraph?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, fonts, styles

Can I apply different styles to the content of a button? For example I have a search box, if user inputs "is" in the search box and click search, can I make the two "is" below in the button content italic font? At the same time, I want to keep the remaining part as it is, no italic.

```
<Button
    Content="This is an example of button content. This is a very long content.">
   <Button.Style>
    ???
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

After apply the style I want the button content:
This *is* an example of button content. This *is* a very long content.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content was static, you could simply define your button like so:

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock>
         <Run Text="This"></Run>
         <Run Text="is" FontStyle="Italic"></Run>
         <Run Text="an example of button content. This"></Run>
         <Run Text="is" FontStyle="Italic"></Run>
         <Run Text="a very long content."></Run>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

or:

```
<Button>
    <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0"> <!-- Other styles as needed -->
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                This
                <Italic>is</Italic> an example of button content. This
                <Italic>is</Italic> a very long content.
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Button>
```

However, for your situation where styles are dynamic, I'd use the following service:

```
// Note: Not my code, but I can't find the original source
public static class RichTextBoxService
{
    public static string GetContent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ContentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetContent(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Content",
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata 
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            PropertyChangedCallback = OnDocumentChanged,
        });

    private static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;

        // Parse the XAML content to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())
        var xaml = GetContent(richTextBox);
        var doc = new FlowDocument();
        var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

        range.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml)), DataFormats.Xaml);

        richTextBox.Document = doc;

        // When the document changes update the source
        range.Changed += (s, args) =>
        {
            if (richTextBox.Document == doc)
            {
                MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
                range.Save(buffer, DataFormats.Xaml);

                SetContent(richTextBox, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray()));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you'd use it with your button like so:

**View:**

```
<Window xmlns:services="clr-namespace:MyProject.Services;assembly=MyProject">

    <Button>
        <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" services:RichTextBoxService.Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
    </Button>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
// Note: I can't remember is Section is required or not
private const string Header = @"<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><Paragraph>";

private const string DefaultContent = "This is an example of button content. This is a very long content";

private const string Footer = "</Paragraph></Section>";

private string _search;
public string Search
{ 
    get { return _search; }
    set {
         if (Set(ref _search, value))  // using MVVMLight
         {
             // search value was updated
             this.ButtonContent = Header + DefaultContent.Replace(value, "<Italic>" + value + "</Italic>") + Footer;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool!! I will try this out! Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me know if there are any errors. I made a few changes from the code that I use and haven't tested that it compiles.

Comment: Have you ever tried more fancy styles on the italic value part? Do you know can I apply any style I would like to this value? Or just simple style like font etc.? DefaultContent.Replace(value, "<Italic>" + value + "</Italic>")

Comment: Yeah, instead of using `<Italic>` you can use `@"<Run Foreground=""Red"" FontWeight=""Bold"">" + value + "</Run>"`, for example

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Content` can be anything, e.g. a `TextBlock` containing a `Run` per word or text segment, which you then can style individually. I do not think that a pure XAML approach is very useful here. If anything you might want to define your highlighting style in the resources somewhere, then apply that style conditionally in code upon user input.

Comment: How to apply a style conditionally in code upon user input? Can you talk more about this or do you have an example so I can refer to?

Comment: It just means assigning the `Style` property if some condition holds, e.g. `if (run.Text.Contains("the")) run.Style = italicStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply define your button like below:

```
                <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="This" />
                    <Run Text="is" FontStyle="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItalicConverter}}" />
                    <Run Text="a..."  />
                </TextBlock>
            </Button.Content>
```

And  then I would use a ValueConverter to check if the user has pressed the other button or not to change the style.

Something like this:

```
    public class ItalicConverter : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
            return "Italic";
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
            return true;
         }
     }
```

You would have to add the logic to convert it back to normal

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually the content is dynamic and the search content is also dynamic. But still thank you!